# How can a .emacs file be made idempotent?

Tags: emacs, elisp, emacs24, dot-emacs, idempotent

No matter how many times I reload my `.emacs` file,

<kbd>M-x load-file RET</kbd> <kbd>~/.emacs RET</kbd>

I want the results to be the same as the first time.  I want to make my `.emacs` file be [***idempotent***](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

### Motivation

I know I can surgically evaluate a region (<kbd>C-c C-r</kbd>), a defun (<kbd>C-M-x</kbd>), or the last sexp (<kbd>C-x C-e</kbd>).  I often take such a more refined approach when making small changes.  However, when re-working a `.emacs` file, I sometimes want to check results of the change conclusively by reloading the entire `.emacs` file.  Restarting emacs each time gets old quick, especially when doing major `.emacs` housekeeping.

### Specific Steps

*What specific steps must I take to update my `.emacs` file to replace non-idempotent operations with idempotent ones?*

For example,

1. Search for "-hook" and replace direct additions to hooks with calls to `add-hook`, which
   will not re-add a function to the hook if already there.
2. Replace toggling of any flags with direct setting or clearing.  Beware of ***??*** in particular.
3. ...

A comprehensive check-and-correct list would be ideal, but any key individual checks that occur to you would be helpful as well.

Comment: The be totally idempotent would be impossible in elisp. Unless you kept track of every definition and knew what to unbind. Especially if you are using a lot of third party packages. You're on the right path with your list there, but ideally you would need to unload all your packages before reevaluation. The way I have found to develop my .emacs nicely is to write it in a way that restarting emacs is not a pain, if your startup time is tiny, then doing development in one instance of emacs and restarting a bunch of times to test your init in another instance isn't a big pain.

Comment: What you could maybe do is do a -Q startup and store everything in the main obarry in a file, then write a function that will unbind everything except what is in -Q obarray and restore all the normal values from your store.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know as it's possible to ensure this completely, as most .emacs files depend on libraries which may not have idempotent initialization routines. However, there are a few useful tricks to reduce problems:

1. Use named functions for `add-hook`, and keybindings instead of anonymous functions. For `add-hook` in particular, this allows it to swap out the existing reference.
2. Careful use of `defvar`, by default the body is only evaluated if the variable is undefined. `C-M-x` on a `defvar` will re-eval the body, but `eval-buffer` will not if the variable is already initialized.
3. Careful use of `(quote function)` instead of `function` to reference a named function instead of the value of the function. See [Anonymous Functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Anonymous-Functions.html) for more advanced discussion about this.
4. Remember that `require` will only load the corresponding library the first time it is executed, it will not re-eval on repeated calls as `load` does. Autoload also uses require to load the corresponding library.
5. Prefer `add-to-list` instead of `cons` to only add an element if it doesn't exist.
6. For older mode activation, make sure to use `(mode-name-mode t)` to activate instead of the toggle function. Likewise for `turn-on-` minor mode functions instead of the mode toggle.
7. Guard blocks that do have side effects if executed repeatedly. In particular for server mode, `(unless (server-running-p) (server-start))`, and similar guards for installing packages.
8. Being careful about side effects in `eval-after-load` or custom mode hooks. Remember the default mode hooks run when a mode is first enabled, and on each subsequent buffer, but will not rerun in existing buffers when the hook function is modified. `eval-after-load` is less likely to trip things up, it's still important to remember when it's evaluated.
9. Related to #2, `makunbound` may be useful if a chain of vars that depend on each other need to be re-evaluated, as it will force the `defvar` to always execute on evaluation of the file.

Running `eval-buffer` on an init file should be as idempotent as possible, but it's important to remember that emacs lisp is fond of side effects and state. While it's possible to ameliorate this to some extent, re-evaling init will never return emacs to the state it was when it first started.

Answer (score 4):

Limit yourself to things you know are idempotent:

- defun.
- setq to a constant.
- add-to-list with a constant.
- add-hook, but preferably adding a symbol rather than a lambda expression.
- enabling/disabling a minor mode.
- wrapping some of the above in conditions.

Of course *idempotent* doesn't actually mean that the result is the same as re-starting (e.g. removing a `setq` and then re-evaluating your .emacs won't remove the effect of the previous setq), but the above is pretty much the principles I try to follow in my own ~/.emacs.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what others have said, load (e.g. `require`) libraries, including 3rd-party libraries, whose loading is idempotent.

Yes, to find that out for a given library you might need to either read the code or experiment. But nowadays libraries are supposed to be idempotent (or close to it), and many are.